# MS Access crashes every time I use Immediate Window

Tags: vba, ms-access, crash

Every time I use the MS Access Immediate Window within the VBA Editor, Access crashes if I type any procedure name followed by the spacebar.

For example, I have a procedure called "CreateCEUploadFile" which takes a string parameter for a year. So, I'd like to type "CreateCEUploadFile "2019". However, as soon as I hit the spacebar after the e of File, Access freezes for a second, then crashes.

I initially thought this was specific to a database I've created. This is a database which was initially created 7 years ago, and has been worked on steadily over that time. So, I tried:

1. Compiling, then compacting and repairing. No change.
2. Decompiling the file. No change.
3. Re-compiling the file. No change
4. Creating a new database file, importing all objects. No change.
5. Restarting the PC. No change.
6. Removing Office (Office 365 Pro), restarting the PC, re-installing Office, re-starting the PC. No change.

I've now experimented, and discovered that the same issue occurs in all database files on this PC (a laptop that I've been using without issues for around 2 years). It also occurs with any call to any function (whether my own or built in), as soon as I hit a character after the function name.

In the immediate window:

```
? now  --> works

? date --> works

? format( --> crashes as soon as I hit the spacebar`
```

I have now just discovered that this same issue occurs in MS Excel's VBA Immediate Window too...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've just found the solution.

Using the old principle of "What's changed since I last got this to work" I discovered that it seems to be a problem with my installation of Dextop.

I wanted to have a way of having multiple virtual desktops, and the built-in virtual desktops system in Windows 10 wouldn't cut it. Every time I do anything in SSMS on one desktop, it's reflected in the other.

So, I had a look around and found good reviews for Dextop. It seemed to work well - I have two different databases open in Access (one on each Desktop), and two different instances of SSMS, one pointing at each server. However, it seems to be this that was causing the Immediate Window to crash the relevant application.

Exit Dextop - all works well. 
Restart Dextop - symptom immediately re-appears.

So now to try to find another alternative to Dextop....